# How to build a propper H2O word2vec training_frame

Tags: word2vec, h2o

How do I build a H2O word2vec training_frame that distinguishes between different document/sentences etc.?

As far as I can read from the very limited documentation I have found, you simply supply one long list of words? Such as

```
'This' 'is' 'the' 'first' 'This' 'is' 'number' 'two'
```

However it would make sense to be able to distinguish – ideally something like this:

```
Name   | ID
This   | 1
is     | 1
the    | 1
first  | 1
This   | 2
is     | 2
number | 2
two    | 2
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

word2vec is a type of unsupervised learning: it turns string data into numbers. So to do a classification you need to do a two-step process:

- word2vec for strings to numbers
- any supervised learning technique for numbers to categories

The [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html) contains links to a categorization example in each of [R](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/rdemo.word2vec.craigslistjobtitles.R) and [Python](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/demos/word2vec_craigslistjobtitles.ipynb). [This tutorial](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/tree/master/h2o-world-2017/nlp) shows the same process on a different data set (and there should be a H2O World 2017 video that goes with that).

By the way, in your original example, you don't just supply the words; the sentences are separated by NA. If you give [h2o.tokenize()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.tokenize.html) a vector of sentences, it will make this format for you. So your example would actually be:

> 'This' 'is' 'the' 'first' NA 'This' 'is' 'number' 'two'

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Though I get that word2vec is unsupervised it doesn’t remove the need for it to be able to distinguish between different id’s – such as documents. Otherwise it will, in my case above, link the words ‘This’ and ‘first’ very close together, even though in the real world those two words are as far apart as possible, as they belong to two different id’s.

Or am I completely off here?

Comment: @EmilLykkeJensen For getting a deeper intuitive feel for what embeddings are doing, my own blog post might help: http://darrendev.blogspot.com/2017/12/word-embeddings-nlp-and-i18n-in-h2o.html   I've used that example at a few talks, at least a couple of which have been videoed and should be online.

Comment: Perfect - thanks @darren-cook. It was the NA sentences separator is was looking for - somehow I cound not see from the h2o doc, that NA is used to split sentences (or other ids).